# Azure BotFramework-WebChat javascript error initializing DirectLine

Tags: azure, botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

Following all the MS guidance I can find relating to web chat and directline, but I keep getting the following error no matter what I try from botchat.js:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'webSocketActivity$'

Once I get the DirectLine connection I'll be following the [backchannel example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#the-backchannel), but I must be missing something because I can't get past the above error. Here's my working code without my DirectLine channel secret:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
    <script>
        var botConnection = BotChat.DirectLine({ secret: <my secret> });
    </script>
    <div id="bot"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `new` to create the directline connection instance:

```
var botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({ secret: <my secret> });
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. I've been staring at this code for WAY too long. That did the trick.